# in cannot be applied to android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please help I just started doing programs in android studio
I was rewriting the program and I had an error and I don't know how to solve it.

```
package com.example.music;

import android.support.design.widget.TabItem;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar;
TabLayout mTabLayout;
TabItem curMusic;
TabItem allMusic;
TabItem playlist;
ViewPager mPager;
PagerController mPagerController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);          /*-------------------------here is an error*/
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tab Music");

    mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    curMusic = findViewById(R.id.currentMusic);
    allMusic = findViewById(R.id.allMusic);
    playlist = findViewById(R.id.playlist);
    mPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    mPagerController = new PagerController(getSupportFragmentManager(),mTabLayout.getTabCount());

    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));

       }
    }
```

error

setSupportActionBar
(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)
in AppCompatActivity cannot be applied
to
(android.widget.Toolbar)

Comment: Share your AndroidManifest.xml, the part that define your activity should have a toolbar `Theme`

Comment: Most likely you just need to change the import from `import android.widget.Toolbar;` to `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of toolbar.  One in the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and one in android.widget.Toolbar and you are trying to mix them.

Change the widget in your layout so the libraries match.